# Deploying code from local environment to Google Action/Dialogflow: Nothing happens

Tags: javascript, npm, webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to make a Google Action in Dialogflow. More specifically I am trying to deploy javaScript code from my terminal. A few days ago the code worked perfectly.

The index.js file that works:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./pathToAccountKey);

let count = 0



admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://voice-c5a55.firebaseio.com/"
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + 
JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welkom gekke banaan!`);
}

function fallback(agent) {
  let conv = agent.conv();
  count++
  console.log("count is " + count)
  if (count === 1){
    agent.add(`poging 1`)
  } else if (count === 2) {
    agent.add(`nu 2`);
  } else {
    return agent.close('Te laat')

  };

}

function voting(agent) {
    let conv = agent.conv(); // Get Actions on Google library conv instance

    let endConversation = false;
    let responseText = '';
    let singer = agent.parameters['kleur'];

    if ( singer !== '' ) {
        let artistName = singer.replace(' ', ''). toLowerCase();
        let currentArtist = admin.database().ref().child('/artists/' + artistName);

        currentArtist.once('value', function (snapshot) {
            if ( snapshot.exists() && snapshot.hasChild('votes') ) {
                let obj = snapshot.val();
                currentArtist.update({
                    votes: obj.votes + 1
                })
            } else {
                currentArtist.set({
                    votes: 1
                })
            }
        });
        responseText = 'Thanks man voor je stem!';
    } else {
      fallback();


    }

    if ( endConversation ) {
        conv.close(responseText);
    } else {
        conv.ask(responseText);
    }
    agent.add(responseText);

}
let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
    intentMap.set('kleur stemmen', voting);
```

The problem is that there seems to be no connection between my local environment and the Actions console. The package.json contains everything there needs to be. I really do not know what to do, again I could deploy and test this code a few days ago but now just nothing happens.

I installed all dependencies using NPM, so that can not be a problem in my opinion. Again, it worked perfectly fine a few days ago. I also checked if all the fulfillments for webhook were enabled, they were.

The deployment from the terminal does not throw any errors. However when I try to test it in the Action Simulator I get the following error:

> {
>     "responseMetadata": {
>       "status": {
>         "code": 10,
>         "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",
>         "details": [
>           {
>             "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
>             "value": "{\"id\":\"ea987ebc-670b-4fd4-b002-dce3a21910eb\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-11-07T15:33:16.59Z\",\"lang\":\"nl\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"errorType\":\"success\"},\"sessionId\":\"ABwppHEMJQALun_4R3ESqXJoEO8JoIs1P9riNuLpNMYbHfGT6XLhxo4EQaj6vmDe1ks-jUZG7-l6A9JkIaE\"}"
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     }
>   }

So it seems to me that something goes wrong in the connection between my terminal and the console. I would really love to get an answer to this question!

UPDATE:

- I tried to deploy using `firebase deploy` The deployment throws no errors whatsoever and reacts exactly the way it did when the code did work so there seems to be no problem there. I also checked if i was in the correct directory.
- Nothing appears in the Firebase logs. As you can see in the code something should appear there but it doesn't.

[Screenshot from the Dialogflow Fulfillment page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCAJD.png)

- Intent handlers are added to the code, they were in there but I copied and pasted it badly.

Comment: By saying you're deploying it, do you mean deploying it using `firebase deploy`?  Can you update your question with the answers to: What is the output of your deployment? When the Action is triggered does anything appear in the Firebase Cloud Functions logs? Can you add a screen shot of the Fulfillment page in Dialogflow?

Comment: Are you sure this index.js file works? I'm seeing a missing quote on your service account line, and I'm not seeing where your agent handles the request intent.

Comment: did you test your local code using ngrok? is there any error coming?

Comment: I updated the question! I do not use Ngrok, checked it out but it looks as if it's going to make things harder for me. Not very experienced but I am willing to look into it if you guys think it could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Webhook in your Dialogflow fulfillment and paste the deployment URL of Firebase functions that are deployed using `firebase deploy`.

Make sure you are using the correct Actions Project

```
firebase use <PROJECT_ID>
```

Your Action's project ID can be found in the Actions Console, under Overview >  (Gear icon) > Project settings.

Refer the following Google Codelabs link to setup connection between your local environment and firebase functions:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/#2